# Access violation reading location 0x00000006

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have the following code which finds the strings that contain no Alphabets. Cases like **mynumber123** shall not be recognized and the **numberFinder()** should return false and case like **123** shall be recognized and **numberFinder()** shall return **true** as well as the **begin index** of the number.

**the constructor:**

```
CaddressParser::CaddressParser(string fileName)     //constructor
{
    m_fileName=fileName;
    int length=getLength(m_fileName.c_str());
    m_text =fileReader(m_fileName.c_str());
    m_length=length;
}
```

which initializes a string `m_text` that contains the contents of a text file

Somewhere along the implementation I come across the following code:

```
for (i;i<m_length;i++)
{
    bool UpperCaseBeforeNoFound=false;

    if(this->numberFinder (i).second)
    {
        //do some calculations.
    }
}
```

the numberFinder function is implemented as follows:

```
pair <int,bool> CaddressParser::numberFinder(int counter)
{
    bool noFound=isdigit(m_text[counter]);      //number found? -> true
    if(noFound)
    {
        int end=HouseNoDigits(counter);
        if(((counter-1)>=0) && ((counter +end-1) <m_length))
        {
            if((!(isalpha(m_text[counter-1]))) && (!isalpha(m_text[counter+end-1])))
            {
                return make_pair(counter,noFound);      //return index if true
            }
        }
     }
     else return make_pair(0,noFound);
 }
```

Now the problem is for a text file containing the following text "***he23 Market street London Q12 H13***". I get the error mentioned in the headline and the debugger takes me to the line in the which contains :

`if(this->numberFinder (i).second)`

I can't figure out why this is happening. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Please fix your indentation so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, "numberFinder" returns NULL (or `this` is NULL)

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth yes sir!

Comment: I think the problem is there is a chance of numberFinder not returning a pair since all control paths do not appear to return.

Comment: What happens if either of the two conditions after if(noFound) are not met?

Comment: Shouldn't your compiler have warned about this?

Comment: Please compile with warnings enabled and fix those warnings.  I bet you will get quite a few that will point you to multiple problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Violation error is normally due to NULL reference. One of the function that you are calling is trying to access a NULL pointer. Make sure your isdigit function returns true or false, m_text points to an exiting memory location. If not you need to allocate the memory. You should also check if the fileName is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

If this condition in `CaddressParser::numberFinder(int counter)` fails:

```
if (counter - 1 >= 0 && counter + end - 1 < m_length)
```

the function will exit without returning a value, resulting in undefined behavior.

The complexity of the conditionals in the function isn't helped by the poor formatting (at least as posted in the question).

You might get the behavior you need by removing the `else` so any 'fall-through' will return the default `pair` value (but that will depend on if that's the value you want to really return in that scenario):

```
pair <int,bool> CaddressParser::numberFinder(int counter)
{
    bool noFound=isdigit(m_text[counter]);      //number found? -> true
    if(noFound)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return make_pair(0,noFound);
}
```